# Referencing to subfigures in main caption

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I'm trying to reference to subfigures in the main caption of my figure. Unfortunately I'm only getting blanks, not even undefined referencing `??`. What's going on?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure1}
    \label{fig:fig1}
    \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure2}
    \label{fig:fig2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\protect\subref{fig:fig1} shows figure 1 and \protect\subref{fig:fig2} shows figure 2.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither of your `subfigure`s actually have a caption. Use `\caption{\label{fig:fig1}}` and `\caption{\label{fig:fig2}}` in both `subfigure`s.

Comment: Yes, I left the captions of the `subfigures` away on purpose. I thought that captions weren't necessary to label subfigures?

Comment: See p 5 of the [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) for an example very similar to yours.

Comment: If there is no `(a)`, it is not nice to link to `a`. The lector wouln't know, what you mean. In this case you should write: `The above shows figure 1 (left) and figure 2 (right)`

Comment: You're absolutely right that it isn't nice to link to `(a)` if there isn't any. However, the figures themselves already have those labels, so that's why I left the subcaptions out on purpose.

Comment: @Robert: If the sub-caption labels are "hard-coded" in the figures, then you might just as well "hard-code" the actual reference to them: `\caption{(a)~shows Figure~1 and~(b) shows Figure~2}`. Because if you wish to switch the `subfigures`, you'd have to change the "hard-coded" image captions as well. As you now know, LaTeX can handle this without the "hard-coding".

Comment: @Robert @Werner When hard-coding the references they don't offer a link when using `hyperref`. For that reason the `subcaption` package offers `\phantomsubcaption`, see also section "Referencing sub-figures without sub-captions" of the `subcaption` documentation.

Answer (score 30):

You need to add a separate `\caption` for each `subfigure` in order to display the label (which can then be referenced):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\label{fig:fig1}}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\label{fig:fig2}}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{\subref{fig:fig1} shows Figure~1 and~\subref{fig:fig2} shows Figure~2.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Taken from the `subcaption` documentation, section "Referencing sub-figures without sub-captions":

If you don’t want to give a sub-figure a caption, because the picture itself already contains
the caption, or for some other reason, you can use the command
`\phantomsubcaption`
instead of `\subcaption`, or – when inside a `subfigure` or `subtable` environ-
ment – `\phantomcaption` instead of `\caption`. `\phantomsubcaption` and
`\phantomcaption` do not have any arguments, and they do not generate any output,
but give you an anchor for a `\label` command which can be placed afterwards. Fur-
thermore it increases the sub-figure resp. sub-table counter.
Please note that – just like `\subcaption` – the `\phantomsubcaption` command
must be applied inside its own group, box, or environment.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure1}
    \phantomcaption
    \label{fig:fig1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure2}
    \phantomcaption
    \label{fig:fig2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\subref{fig:fig1} shows figure 1 and \subref{fig:fig2} shows figure 2.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note: `\phantomsubcaption` needs `subcaption` version 1.1 (2011/08/17) or newer.

Comment: If you don't want the hyperlink in the caption (seems a bit silly to do, esp. for a single row figure), consider using `\subref*` instead of `\subref`